# right click in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, ag-grid, right-click

I'm trying to right click an element using protractor, the element is a cell in an ag-grid.

I'm trying to use some of the earlier suggestions that I could find, the only one that didn't throw me an error was the following:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(elementVar).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

although it doesn't right-click at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be a hacky workaround (and one of the solutions you already tried), but maybe try telling it to hold down another button and then perform a normal click? i.e. on Mac, if you hold CTRL and do a click, it acts like a right click. Looks like it would be `keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform()` followed by the click event?

Comment: First of all, thanks! I've learned something new with this CTRL in mac. But unfortunately, when I use it in my app it gives me the right-click menu of chrome, and not the one of the grid that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer for that one. I was really close, but for the ones to look for this question the solution is this:

the elementVar you are passing to the mouseMove function, should be the desired element **location**. What does it mean?
For example lets say we have an element called 'el' that we want to right click on it, our code needs to be like:

```
async function rightClick (el) {
    loc = el.getLocation();    //get the location of the element we want to click
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(loc).perform();   //takes the mouse to hover the element
    await browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();    //performs the right click
};
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [webdriverJs api](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ActionSequence.html), you can right click an element thusly:

```
browser.actions()
    .click($('.myElm'), protractor.Button.RIGHT)
    .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Brine's answer, I managed to work out a method without the mousemove stuff or the Jquery.

```
import { protractor } from 'protractor/built/ptor';

const ele = element(by.id('my_element');
browser.actions().click(ele, protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite sure is not a clean solution but all the script above are ok if you are using a headless chrome. 
If you are using a normal chrome ant the above solutions are not working, give a try at this workaround:

```js
        await browser.actions().mouseMove(elementFinder).mouseDown().mouseMove(elementFinder).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my `protractor.conf.js` worked for me:

```
{
  capabilities: {
    chromeOptions: {
      w3c: false
    }
  }
}
```

from https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5271