# Right click is not performed in protrcator tests instead a left click is performed

Tags: jasmine, protractor, node-modules

I am Trying to perform a right click using the below code

```
try {
             browser.actions().mouseMove(RFVModeling.FirstRowCreatediagonal).click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform().then(function () {
        log.info('Right click Succesfull')
        RFVModeling.CreateDiagonallink.click();
        log.info('Created diagonal elements')
    })

    browser.sleep(5000)
   }catch (e) {
       console.log("", e);
       log.error(e.message, e);
   }
```

instead of performing `rightclick` it is performing a left click on the element .
But i am able to perform Right click if i change my config to `directConnect= 'true`
and if i do so many of my test's which where working fine with selenium server on will Fail so i don't want to use `directConnect=true` in my config and want to perform Right click on the elements please let me know a proper solution for the same if any ..
Node=v13.6.0
protractor=5.4.2
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right click in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631069/right-click-in-protractor) - apparently, you should `mouseMove` to the element's location, not the element itself.

Comment: @SpinyNorman  Thanks for reply ,but my question is different i have issue in right click only if i don't use directConnect : true and i use selenium standalone server to run my tests .As I have already mentioned in my question regarding same .i am able to perform the right click if i use directConnect : true

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Comment: thanks ,but i have already tried the above code as well but my question is if i use directConnect:true the above mentioned code runs fine but if i use the selenium standalone server to run tests then it is performing the left click for the same code

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been aware of this, it might be issue with the selenium standalone server. Update it to the latest version maybe that will help