# How to perform right click in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have tried almost everything via stack overflow answers([right click in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631069/right-click-in-protractor)) for the same but still not able to perform right click.

Below what I have used:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(locator).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Comment: you don't move mouse to a locator... you need to move mouse to an element, found with the locator

Comment: Yes Sergey I know, Just for an example I have mentioned as a location otherwise I am passing an element here.

Answer (score 1):

We have to first get the element location then move to that element and later perform right click on it.

```
rightclick: async () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                let el = locator.Loginscreen.submit; // element(by.css('#okta-signin-submit'))
                let loc = await el.getLocation();    //get the location of the element we want to click
                await browser.actions().mouseMove(loc).perform();   //takes the mouse to hover the element
                await browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();    //performs the right click
            }
            catch (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
        })
    }
```

check this method in screenshot

[image]

When i run it is able to right on the submit button in login screen

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bharat for the detailed answer but this solution is not working for my user where on right click it opens up a context menu. I can see that its working for other sites but not in my case. I have tried almost everything. Can you suggest something with Javascript executor I am wondering if that will work?

Comment: @QA_hacks did you crack the solution?

Comment: Kumar S : I came to know that right click isn't supported for chrome browser version above version 74. This is the reference:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5271